# Why sorting data in report viewer2010 doesn`t work?

Tags: sorting, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I use report viewer 2010 and I want to make interactive sort on each column from my report.
I set in the rdlc file on each column the interactive sort in the Sort by field an expressions like:

```
=Fields!ClientName.Value
```

but when i run my report and click on the header icon it seems to do a refresh but after the data is not ordered. I tried to order the data in the dataSource but it does not work. My data is always sorted by the first column in the table. If I change this first column the data will be sorted after the change, but I want to sort by other columns.

Answer (score 3):

Look if you have some default sort on the row, in the grouping property. I had this problem once and this was the solution for me.

Comment: It also helped to check sort order for group vs. sorting for detail rows. Thank you for giving right direction for digging though.